# How to stop asking admin name?

Tags: macos

Both Linux & OS X ask for admin name/password for some important things. It's ok. But Linux saves the previosly entered admin name, and Mac doesn't. How to make my Mac remember it? So that I would enter only the password.

**UPD:** I'm running a standard user account.

Comment: Are you using an admin user account? Usually, OS X fills our your name already.

Answer (score 0):

I've get this when I'm running a standard user account and it needs elevated permissions to do something (assuming it's done by design). However, if I'm logged in as an admin then is always fills in the username.